# vs code is not creating the file in

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create file in vs code and this file is note creating in my current dir and it give the error like this

> Permission denied writing to file (file:///home/tentron/hello-world/src/app/courses.component.ts)

I am using **linux mint**

when I try to open code as root user `(sudo code "folder_name" <-|)`
it gave me warning like this

> You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument.

I can't understand this `' --user-data-dir argument '`
and how to use it

Comment: did you check the permissions of the files in the project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vscode, I don't recommend you to launch code as super user, but here is how:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir=/enter/path/here/
```

bear in mind that that the given dir will populate with a lot of vscode files and folders.

However, I would first check if you have writing permissions on the file you want to write/edit. In linux you can try `sudo chmod 766 file_name` that should give any user write permission.